# How to Flurry intigration? how can .mov file working in android?

Tags: android, flurry

i am using flurry api in my application their is a .mov file is genrating error. i can't handle how to solved this issue in my apps. when i am trying to load a flurry video at that time it will generate rendering failed.

i hope someone have solved this error so please let me help here.